# Restrict user to delete file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, file, restriction

Hello guys i am trying to make a functionality in my application so that user should not be able to delete file within folders and icons on desktop...till now i am able to do is that user can't open a folder but when i am giving FileSystemRights to delete then it is not working...how can i achieve this please help me ....

here is my code..

```
     public string p = @"D:\\test";
     public string SysLogUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    public void FreezeFile(string path, string user)
    {


        System.IO.DirectoryInfo folderinfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectorySecurity foldersecurity = folderinfo.GetAccessControl();
        FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(user, FileSystemRights.ReadData, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny);

        foldersecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(path, foldersecurity);
    }
    private void btn_Action_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FreezeFile(p,SysLogUser);
        MessageBox.Show("Permissions Altered Successfully");
    }
```

Comment: is it a heavy client app ? why would you like to do this ?

Comment: FileSystemRights.ReadData ? surely you mean FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles as you've just blocked them from reading files

Comment: yeah...it's kind of e learning application where teacher and students will be involved...so student can't delete any file

Comment: yeah...blocking them from reading file is working fine but filesystems.delete or filesystems.deletesubdirectoriesandfolder is not working